# AVPlayer fails to playback .mov uploaded to server

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer

I have uploaded a .mov file to my server and it fails to playback in my app, this code works fine with another url I tested:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) 
{
    let destination = segue.destinationViewController as 
            AVPlayerViewController
    let url = NSURL(string: 
    "http://shahnewazkhan.ca/iOS/henrik_penalty_shot.mov")
    destination.player = AVPlayer(URL: url)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The uploaded file exceeds the hosting plan limit. See from your console:

```
     curl http://shahnewazkhan.ca/iOS/henrik_penalty_shot.mov
```

The uploaded file exceeds the hosting plan limit. Please, consider upgrading to a more powerful hosting package.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I uploaded the file to a vps and it works fine now.